# Fatal error: Index out of range in TableView inside ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Essentially I have a TableView inside a ViewController called `TransferTableView` my intention is to have data load from a function called `fetchJSON()` that populates the tableView with both rows and section for organization.

The issue is I keep getting the error,

> Fatal error: Index out of range in TableView inside ViewController.

For the line `let section = sections[section]` in `numberOfRowsInSection` I don't understand what is causing this error to appear.

Comment: did you print sections array ? it could be empty before you access sections[section]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the table appears before loading the data the array is empty and default of `numberOfSections` is 1

```
let section = sections[section] // = sections[0]
```

hence the crash , you fix it by adding

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
  return sections.count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this func in your datasource

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
  return sections.count
}
```